# Get a colored UIImage using extension

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I try to get a colored image (star.jpg, just a star icon) using one extension. As result I get colored the whole `UIImageView` including my image. How could I get only `UIImage` colored?

Here is the code I used:
UIImage+Tinting.swift

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

func tintWithColor(color:UIColor)->UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Flip the image
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -self.size.height)

    // Multiply blend mode
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Multiply)

    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage)
    color.setFill()
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

    // Create uiimage
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let myImageview = UIImageView()
let myImage = UIImage(named: "star.jpg")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    myImageview.image = myImage
    let img = myImageview.image
    myImageview.image = img?.tintWithColor(UIColor.redColor())

    // Set position of the image view
    myImageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //Don't forget this line
    view.addSubview(myImageview)

    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myImageview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myImageview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myImageview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myImageview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 0.3, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: problem is with you image, Image(star) which you are using should have alpha particles, As you want to change color of star only, you need to create a PNG image of star and rest with alpha value, then apply Imbue's code in given answer.

Comment: i have added sample code and image in answer, pls check.

Comment: Roman have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, you are so right! The problem was with the image itself. I changed it and now the very first answer works. Thank you so much.

Comment: I added answer to apply tint color and sample image. Always welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "yourimage");
    let tintedImage = image!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
    imageView.image = tintedImage

    view.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

**UPDATE**

Tried copying you're exact setup, without the context drawing in the extension, and making an extension based tint (Not that it's very smart, at the functions is already implemented as a standard in swift, but just for the fun of it)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

private var myImageview : UIImageView!
private var myImage : UIImage!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myImage = UIImage(named: "double-arrow")
    myImageview = UIImageView(frame: view.frame)

    myImageview.image = myImage.makeTintable()

    view.addSubview(myImageview)

    myImageview.tintTo(UIColor.purpleColor())
}

}

extension UIImageView{
   func tintTo(color:UIColor){
       self.tintColor = color
   }
}

extension UIImage{
    func makeTintable() -> UIImage{
    return self.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try to implement it I just get the whole view red. Even the star icon is disappeared. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Have you tried initializing the imageview and image in the viewDidLoad() instead of outside it? I updated my answer, to an extension based answer instead, using some of your code, without the context drawing though.

Comment: I try to repeat and get on my imageview colored in purple. Sorry

Comment: Your PNG may be completely colored then and without transparent pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to change Appearance of UIImageView image using tintColor. Also provided sample image with Alpha channel.

```
// *** I assume you have define IBOutlet of your imageView or programatically created ***
@IBOutlet weak var ivStar: UIImageView!

// *** Set `UIImage` with rendering mode `AlwaysTemplate`
ivStar.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "Star").imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)

// *** Set TintColor on `UIImageView` as per your Appearance requirement ***
ivStar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor();
```

**Sample Star icon with Alpha PNG**

[image: Star icon PNG]

Comment: Cool. Happy Coding :)